# Multiple Versions of Android App For Testing

Tags: android, version-control, configuration, apk, google-play-console

I have an Android app that is currently on an Internal Test Track (Version 1).  I am trying to upload a new version (Version 2), but I want my current users to still test Version 1.

The console will not let me retain Version 1.

Is there a way I can have user Group A test Version 1 and user Group B test Version 2?

I did try using an Internal Test and Alpha test.  But the Alpha version was downloaded to both groups even when only a single group was selected for it.

Answer (score 4):

All the explanations are [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

Summary:

- you can only have one internal test
- you can have multiple closed tests, but users need to opt-in

It sounds like you want to have version 1 on a (new) closed track and will need to get your existing users to opt-in to that, and rmeove them from the internal test

Then have version 2 on a new internal test track that targets group B.

The other option would not be to have an internal test track at all, and have two closed test tracks, one for Group A, and one for Group B.

Internal test tracks are normally for very quick release for developers or immediate QA within your own company. Closed test tracks are usually trusted testers, or for people within your company not necessarily within the development team who can wait a little bit for the rollout to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've read that page and never connected the closed test tracks to being able to test different versions. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to create a new closed track with version 1, but I get the following error: You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. If you are testing two different versions on two different tracks you need two different version codes

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a whole answer to your problem, but I have figured out that you can send people links to download a certain version of the app with 'Internal App Sharing' on the Google Play Console.

So yeah, set up 'Internal App Sharing'. (Sorry, I'm too lazy to write up steps on how to do that.)

After I set that up, when I use the 'App bundle explorer' to observe an apk or app bundle, there is a Downloads tab:
[image]

And I copied that shareable link and sent it to my phone. And then I opened that shareable link on my phone. I had to enable internal app sharing in my google play store settings (look this up because it's not obvious how to do it) on my phone. And then the link sent me to a page where I could download that specific version.

Not sure if this type of thing could be used to solve your problem but it's worth a shot.